# How to display a Shapefile on a browser? -offline-

Tags: shapefile, html, browser

Plot points on a **Shapefile** like this: https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode
and then convert it to **HTML** and display it on a browser?

Is this practical method to display the map on a browser?
Any cons of it?

**Is there any other way of displaying a Shapefile on a browser?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/shapefile-js/simple.html
and

http://badassjs.com/post/845509816/rendering-binary-shapefiles-with-javascript

both use javscript for rendering the shapefile

Comment: thanks, but does it work "offline"? `It loads the binary data using an *AJAX request*`

Comment: This does work Online and Offline in IE - blog post http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2010/07/esri-shapefile-html5-viewer.html

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your shapefile to [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) and use tools like [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to Display it in an HTML page.

To convert a shapefile to GeoJSON you can use [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (It's a great GIS tool). and also there is online convertion services: http://ogre.adc4gis.com/ or http://www.mapshaper.org/

Answer (score 2):

checkout shp2Mapstraction.py [here](http://perrygeo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gis-bin/shp2Mapstraction.py) which makes your point data to html with desired map provider.(in this trunk you can find more files for some purposes.)

Usage:

```
shp2Mapstraction.py worker.shp workers.html Yahoo
```

and [here](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2007/12/10/quick-way-to-publish-a-point-shapefile-to-web/) there is some information about it.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Can that work "offline"?

Comment: Yes. It creates offline html file but provider have to be online....

Comment: I mean to ask that will I be able to see the map when the internet is not working?