# Displaying Shapefiles in map in browser and not using Google Maps

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping, software-recommendations, php, apache

I have a series of shapefiles that I need to render as a map on a webpage. I have an ASP.Net server, although I would prefer something that will work on Linux servers. I would like to find an easy to set up opensource or freeware solution if at all possible. This cannot be overlaid over Google maps. It is just a map of the county I live in and that is all that needs to be shown. The shapefiles consist of the streets, boundary lines, street names, etc. Each one is a separate shapefile. This map will need to be zoomable as well.

I do not have a copy of ArcGIS so I cannot do any conversions with it. Although I have QGIS installed. It's server is giving me issues though.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29612/how-to-display-a-shapefile-on-a-browser-offline

Comment: Have you checked How to start web mapping? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping

Comment: Do you need the map in background and want to show other things over it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on what you want & need. You may only need "dead" bitmaps, or you may need "alive" objects in your client.

There are numerous solutions out there, depending on your needs.

You need a client in your browser, [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) is perhaps the most prefered open source solution.

As for the service backends, e.g WMS and WFS, [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) and [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/) are good candidates. Both of these supports shapefiles. Also, both of these runs on multiple OS'es, of course including Linux.

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution to serve up shapefiles on a basemap in a webapp is through a free arcgis.com account. They allow you upload .shp files, symbolize, and lay them on a base map. The share tool allows provides a html script that can be copied. I served up some symbolized counties to my blogger page in a webmap. Note that ESRI is trying to monetize arcgis.com but this did work recently.

Oyvind's post is valid as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the shapefiles to geojson or gml or kml.
 After that you can use and tweak the examples in [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.org) to display your data.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up your own server seems like a lot of work in order to serve a simple map of a small area, especially if you don't already have experience in doing so.

I think your time would be much more wisely spent using a hosted web mapping product. You could put a fully featured map together in [MangoMap](http://www.mangomap.com) in an hour or two  without having to write a single line of code. Or if you want to write some code to do some heavier customisation you should look at [Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com) which will allow all the mapping stuff to be done on their server and you have the client code on your server.

Comment: You really should put in a disclaimer that you are the CEO of MangoMaps, if you are suggesting it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

for a quick solution, you can check out [shapefile-js](https://github.com/RandomEtc/shapefile-js).

```
A binary shapefile loader and canvas-based renderer, for javascript. Many caveats.
```

test it:

http://www.prodevelop.es/files/fm/public/downloads/jldominguez/shp.html

more info:

Rendering local shapefiles with HTML5

http://www.prodevelop.es/en/blog/11/12/11/rendering-local-shapefiles-html5

and my another answer about this topic [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29616/3071).

[image]
*image is taken from* [jldominguez's blog](http://www.prodevelop.es/en/blog/11/12/11/rendering-local-shapefiles-html5)